# Grails Spring Security Plugin extended User class constructor not setting field values

Tags: grails, spring-security

My application has two types of users (Instructor and Student).

I have added firstName and lastName fields to the User class generated by Spring Security Plugin since all users are expected to have a first and last name.  I subclass 'User' for 'Instructor' and 'Student' to represent my two types of users.  Instructor and Student are Grails Domain Classes.

I am creating test users in Bootstrap.groovy.  I can create a new 'User' object with no problem.

When I try to create a new 'Student' or 'Instructor' object, the firstName and lastName fields are null when set via the constructor.

Spring Security Plugin User class:

```
class User {
    transient springSecurityService

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String username
    String password
    ...
}
```

Student class:

```
class Student extends User{
    String grade
}
```

This works - Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def myUser = new User(username: 'fred', password: '1234', firstName: 'Fred', lastName: 'Jones')
printLn "Last name is ${myUser.lastName}"
```

Prints `Last name is Jones` to the console as expected.

If I try to do the same with the 'Student' subclass - Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def myUser = new Student(username: 'fred', password: '1234', firstName: 'Fred', lastName: 'Jones', grade: 'Junior')
printLn "Last name is ${myUser.lastName}"
```

Prints `Last name is null` to the console not what I expected!

I tried the same with plain vanilla domain classes (not the User class) and I have no problem.  I feel like something special is happening with the 'User' class as part of Spring Security initialization that prevents the subclass from setting the super properties but I can't find any documentation on it.

I can workaround it by setting the properties after I initialize the subclass but I am not sure that is the right way to do it - Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def myUser = new Student(username: 'fred', password: '1234', firstName: 'Fred', lastName: 'Jones', grade: 'Junior')
myUser.lastName = "Woot"
printLn "Last name is ${myUser.lastName}"
```

Prints `Last name is Woot` in the console as expected.

Can someone explain why this is happening?  Is there a better way for me to manage my domain model?

Comment: You can have one User object and create different roles for the students and instructors. Another option is to create the Student/Instructor classes but instead of having them extend User, just have them contain a User